# The atan2 function and axis directions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, trigonometry

In [this ActionScript reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2%28%29) on the `atan2` function, it reads:

> Computes and returns the angle of the point y/x in radians, when
>   measured **counterclockwise** from a circle's x axis (where 0,0 represents
>   the center of the circle). The return value is between positive pi and
>   negative pi. Note that the first parameter to atan2 is always the y
>   coordinate.

For example

```
Math.atan2(0.7071, -0.7071)
```

(note that the first parameter is the Y coordinate) returns 2.356, which is positive Pi*3/4.

But in Flash graphics the Y axis goes down, not up. Shouldn't it be "clockwise" instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the general description of what the atan2 function does in all programming languages.

With that said, you have to indeed put atan(-dy,dx) to get the counter-clock wise angle in screen coordinates, or atan2(dx,dy) to get the zero angle pointing upwards.

Comment: Only if they directly refer to screen coordinates. I think this is just copied from another documentation, perhaps C header math.h, or Java class Math, or the Python math module or ... Sometimes it is better to stay consistent with the general use of the language and document when to expect deviating results.